# receiving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException but cannot figure out why

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, variable-assignment

this is a university assignment (sample academic report), I thought I was done and going to submit but when I started testing... I keep receiving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on line 60  in main and I cannot see why. I am new to Java but really put a lot of hours into this program. Any help/advice is much appreciated.
line 60 =  "int credits = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);"   //im thinking error is something to due with data types??? im lost.

Course / Grade / Report classes pass data to the main java2pgm1

Comment: did you check what is the value of string variable course?

Comment: ERROR=     run:
     Exception in thread "main"     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
     at java2pgm1.Java2pgm1.main(Java2pgm1.java:60)
     Java Result: 1
     BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)

Comment: Hi, yes thank you. here is the value of String course. course = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a course");
            String[] input = course.split(":");

Comment: no.. the value of course should be the input by user in inputDialogue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call split it returns you the an array. Here you are splitting using (":")
You need to check the length of variable input before accessing it.

```
    String[] input = course.split(":");
    int credits = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
```

The input array may not contain more than 1 value so it fails

Comment: the input = CGS1920:1:b:201201.  per assignment no validation needed and assuming the input is always in the proper format

Comment: Learn more about ArrayIndexOutofBoundException. It has nothing to do with datatype. It's related to the length of array. If you input is essentially CGS1920:1:b:201201 then your array should have 4 values and code should work

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the guidance! appreciate help.  please look for me one more thing, after this block of code you will see the code for entering q to exit loop ... will this possibly be part of the problem but the exit does not split after q is entered

Comment: I am not sure I understood your query about exit.. may be you can specify the line number. But again the exception you are getting should only be related to the size of array

Answer (score 0):

The exception will occur when the input from a user does not correspond to the expected format `course_number:number_of_credits:grade_received:term_taken`. In your case for what input value are you running into this exception? Does it contain a `:`?

Suggest that you test the length of the `input` array before referencing index[n]

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into it and try to find my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] input = course.split(":");
int credits = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
Integer term = Integer.parseInt(input[3]);
Course cObject = new Course(input[0],credits,input[2],input[3]);
```

The above snippet in your main always assumes that the `course` String has abc:def:ghi:jkl atleast 3 ":" in it. It is always good practice to handle the error case, when the string doesn't have 3 ":". Modify your code to something like below

```
String[] input = course.split(":");
if(input.length == 4)
{
    int credits = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
    Integer term = Integer.parseInt(input[3]);
    Course cObject = new Course(input[0],credits,input[2],input[3]);
}
else
{
    //show some error message to user
}
```

Comment: That makes sense so the program can handle different amount of : in the input data. Thank you for the advice!  =)

Answer (score 0):

here size of input array may be 0 or 1, you can check it by `input.length`.
If size of array is less or equal the element you want to get from array then runtime exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.